# die Forderung ruhig zu bleiben

Tags: grammar-identification

> Viele in Deutschland schienen zu glauben, **die Forderung ruhig zu bleiben** und Einschränkungen des eigenen Lebens auf ein Minimum zu vermeiden, gehörten zu einer offenen Gesellschaft.

I do not understand the bolded parts sentence structure

For me "die Forderung" seems not to be a object of verb "bleiben" reaming possibility is to be a subject though I do not encounter "subject + zu" structure

Comment: We don't do translation requests. In order for you to get help here, please tell us specifically what is problematic for you. Do you have a suggestion what it could mean?

Comment: For me "die Forderung"  seems not to be a object of verb "bleiben" reaming possibility is to be a subject though I do not encounter "subject + zu" structure

Comment: @ughitudhi I t means _"the claim for keeping calm"_

Comment: Why a downvote? No reason for doing so.

Comment: @infinitezero This is definitely not a translation request! Such requests are introduced by "How do you translate into German...?" Moreover, the OP states clearly, "I do not understand ". This calls clarification!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it's not a claim but a demand.

Comment: I upvoted, and the answer. There is, though, a little logic problem in the phrase: "die Einschränkung ... auf ein Minimum ... zu vermeiden" makes no sense, "beschränken" oder "befolgen" instead of vermeiden would be a better choice, depending on intention. Just sayin' ...

Comment: It would be helpful to be more specific, i.e. explaining which words of the phrase you understand and what your attempt to understand the whole phrase leads to; where it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 5):

When a German verb that takes complements is nominalized like this, then the resulting noun takes the same complements. Hence,

> die Forderung[,] ruhig zu bleiben

=

> the demand to keep calm.

(This mostly works for *verbal* complements only. An accusative object would not transfer to the noun form.)

Comment: Other examples include "Die Wahrscheinlichkeit zu stürzen" or "Die Warnung nicht aufs Eis zu gehen". (probability to fall / warning not to go on the ice)